# Browserify require clashes with node require

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, npm, browserify

As the title suggests, i use browserify for my internal requires and on my node server that interferes with the require of global modules.

My solution now is to build the server script with browserify on the side, and then append a file that holds all my requires of global variables that are later gonna be used by the script. This renders browserify unable to try to put my global npm modules into my server script.

Is there a prettier solution to this? Because this way feels like a heap of dung.

**-- EDIT --**

The code runs only on backend, however - the problem is partially due to how i compile the code that is to be run on that backend. Initially the require keyword is used to get global node modules, e.g express or http. In my case, i need both that functionality as well as reference my own modules compiled with browserify.

My solution right now is to overwrite the global 'define' parameter with [amdefine](https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine) after i've saved references to the the global node modules that i will later use.

[Code to bundle node modules into global parameters, require looks for global node modules](http://www.codeshare.io/EDS0O)
[My Main, everything from this point forward, require looks for modules inside my own code](http://codeshare.io/EDS0O)

I guess I could make a duplicate of nodes require and make a new global reference to it, i.e, require becomes requireNodeModule, i feel as if that's an even worse solution to the one i have at present though...

Comment: Browserify is for the front end - why are you using it for the backend when node.js already manages the `requires`?

Comment: I guess what would be helpful - is how exactly are you using `browserify` for "internal requires"

Comment: Sorry, I phrased is bluntly. I dont use browserify for the backend, what happens is that the 'require' keyword will clash because of the two ways it's used. On one hand it's used by browserify to build the script for my node server, on the other hand i need to use the require keyword to use global node modules running on my server inside that same script. If require the node modules in the same scope as browserify is compiled, it will look for my node modules when it compiles the script - and all hell breaks loose. Hope that clears things up

Comment: Code sample? Interested to see how you are doing it.

Comment: Sure! This is how my "before" part looks: http://www.codeshare.io/oL2pL , and the Main : http://www.codeshare.io/EDS0O

Comment: The perfect solution would be if there was some kind of start and end "ignore tags" for browserify, that way i wouldn't have to append the rest of the code after browserify was done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some code that runs both on the front-end and back-end, but at present this question is too broad for me to give you useful advice.

Can you narrow it down to a single, specific module that you want to run both in the browser and on your server, where the `require` clash is evident?